# Unable to show CSS when running JSP page

Tags: css, jsp

I read almost all the posts on this issue and so far no solutions have worked.

- My CSS is outside the WEB-INF folder;
- I've tried the "${pageContext.request.contextPath}" with no avail;
- I've tried the following servlet mapping in my web.xml but it causes a **NoTargetForURIException**:

The error :

```
PageNotFound  W org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/webapp/css/util.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'cm-dispatcher'
```

My JSP :

```
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/util.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

**HELP!**

Answer (score 0):

Try to give the exact path like localhost:8080/css/example.css. that is refer it with absolute path. Your problem will be solved.Since it is outside the WEB-INF it can be only resolved by doing this.

Use the absolute path to the Css while importing it.

Comment: May be in that case you need to define a mapping for your css too. But thats easy to do since you are using Spring.

Comment: When I try to access my css through the absolute path in a browser(http://localhost:9080/webapp/css/util.css), I get a "no mapping found" error.

When I try to add the <mvc:annotation-driven />, I get "Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException". I do have both "validation.api-1.0.0.GA.jar" and "hiberbate-validator-4.3.0.Final.jar" jars.